# Why Google PageSpeed Insight will take button(with hover effect) as animation?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I run Google PageSpeed Insight on my page https://www.datanumen.com

It reports the following issues:

[image]

I check back with my page, and find these are not animations at all, instead, they are just buttons. When mouse hovers on them, they will change color. Why they are taken as non-composited animation and how to solve the issues?

Comment: Could you provide URLs where these buttons are shown?

Comment: I have provided the URL https://www.datanumen.com, in this page, when you scroll down, you can see "Detailed Information" button and "Custom List" button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count you have to remove the transition effects for your buttons.

```
a.btn, a.button, .inner-page-contact form button, .testimonial-form-holder button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {

    /* -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; */
```

Comment: Thank you. Do these transition really work? I disable these rules in Chrome and cannot find any difference when hovering on the buttons?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the anmiation issue disappears.